# Need to loop a block of code using while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

The content is comming from a query and I dont whant to manually generate a long and repetitive block of code, so I thoght it would work nice if I put the first chunk into a while loop but, nothing good comes out of it.

Here is what I got so far...

```
<?php
  $bloq_1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10);
  $blnu_1 = '1';
  while( $bloq_1=$numeral_1) {
  echo $numeral_1="<article class=\"notxtras\">
    <a class=\"notxtras_url_cntn\" href=\"cdn.php?".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['pltfrm']."=".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['notid']."\" title=\"".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['ttl']."\">
    <div class=\"notxtras_img_cntn\">
      <img src=\"http://cadenanoticias.mx/img/miniatura/".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['pic1'] ."\" alt=\"".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['rlcn'] ."\">
    </div>
    <h1 class=\"notxtras_ttl_cntn\">".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['ttl']."</h1>
    <p class=\"notxtras_brv_cntn\">".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['brv'] ."</p>
    <p class=\"notxtras_dsp_cntn\">Por:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['aut'] ." &bull; ".$tema_s[$blnu_1++]['cdd']." &bull; ".ucfirst(strftime("%A %e de %B del %Y",date(strtotime($tema_s[$blnu_1++]['fch'])))) ."</p>
    </a>
  </article>";
  }
?>
```

Is it posible?

Comment: You're much better off with something like `foreach ($bloq_1 as $n) {`.

Comment: What does your `$tema_s` look like? `$blnu_1++` will increment that variable each time you use it.

Comment: You might also want to look in to some template library. e.g: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Yes... It's not working... I'm bad at loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$bloq_1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10);
foreach ($bloq_1 as $blnu_1) {
    echo "<article class=\"notxtras\">
    <a class=\"notxtras_url_cntn\" href=\"cdn.php?" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['pltfrm'] . "=" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['notid'] . "\" title=\"" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['ttl'] . "\">
    <div class=\"notxtras_img_cntn\">
      <img src=\"http://cadenanoticias.mx/img/miniatura/" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['pic1'] . "\" alt=\"" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['rlcn'] . "\">
    </div>
    <h1 class=\"notxtras_ttl_cntn\">" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['ttl'] . "</h1>
    <p class=\"notxtras_brv_cntn\">" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['brv'] . "</p>
    <p class=\"notxtras_dsp_cntn\">Por:&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['aut'] . " &bull; " . $tema_s[$blnu_1]['cdd'] . " &bull; " . ucfirst(strftime("%A %e de %B del %Y", date(strtotime($tema_s[$blnu_1]['fch'])))) . "</p>
    </a>
  </article>";
}
```

Comment: Thank You... Thhat was it. Wonderfull. You nailed it good. I tried the foreach and now I see why it whas not working ... I was using an equal sign (=) instead of the "as" condition. Thank you alot.

Comment: @SamRamSan, you're welcome. Even though I had my time with PHP I still remember being confused with foreach loops when I just started :)

Answer (score 2):

I have three suggestions/comments:

1. If the content comes from a query, it would probably be better to use `foreach` to iterate over the actual query results (which appear to be stored in `$tema_s`), rather than iterating over a range of numbers. I don't know exactly how `$tema_s` is populated, but if it's like most other query results I've seen, you're probably missing item 0 if you use `[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]`. If you're doing this in order to only show ten results, it would be much better to add a `LIMIT` clause to your query so you won't be fetching more data than you need.
2. In cases where you find yourself echoing lots of HTML, it may be better to exit from PHP to produce the HTML, and just echo values from PHP where you need them. This will prevent the annoyance of escaping all those quotes, and the mess it will create when you miss one (not saying you have in this case, but it's quite easy to do.)
3. None of your variables have been properly escaped for HTML output.

---

Adjusting the code according to these ideas would be something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($tema_s as $item):
    $query_string = urlencode($item['pltfrm']. '=' .$item['notid']);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($item['ttl']);
    $src = urlencode($item['pic1']);
    $alt = htmlspecialchars($item['rlcn']);
    $date = ucfirst(strftime("%A %e de %B del %Y", date(strtotime($item['fch']))));
?>
<article class="notxtras">
    <a class="notxtras_url_cntn" href="cdn.php?<?= $query_string ?>" title="<?= $title ?>">
        <div class="notxtras_img_cntn">
            <img src="http://cadenanoticias.mx/img/miniatura/"<?= $src ?>" alt="<?= $alt ?>">
        </div>
        <h1 class="notxtras_ttl_cntn"><?= $title ?></h1>
        <p class="notxtras_brv_cntn"><?= htmlspecialchars($item['brv']) ?></p>
        <p class="notxtras_dsp_cntn">
            Por:&nbsp;&nbsp;"<?= htmlspecialchars($item['aut']) ?>
            &bull; <?= htmlspecialchars($item['cdd']) ?>
            &bull; <?= $date ?>
        </p>
    </a>
</article>";
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments on your question, you should consider looking into a template system, such as twig. It may seem like overkill for what you're doing here, but it takes care of a lot of this kind of stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you, the thing is that I need to insert 5 articles, have some other static content after and than insert next 5 articles, I whanted to do this in a single query instead of having a query every time I need a block of articles. The #0 resoult nees to be on a separate div so it's published using an if statement.